# stuck on git revert --abort with conflict

Tags: git

So these are my 3 latest commits

commit cb5f9f58885049c20ea7d75e3fcc120f61f6d9a1
commit bad20788aa8b72622182cf28195b4b4e518d44a3
commit eeb8a571e300b52cd0c200351872467c47a32214

I want to revert bad207~ commit (oh, the irony), so I run:

```
git revert bad20788aa8b72622182cf28195b4b4e518d44a3
```

There is a conflict, bad207 and cb5f touch the same file:

```
You are currently reverting commit bad2078.
  (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)
```

So I fix the conflict and run:

```
git add conflicted_file
```

And then:

```
git revert --continue
```

Which outputs (in spanish, it means, on branch master, your branch is updated with origin/master):

```
En la rama master
Su rama está actualizada con «origin/master».
You are currently reverting commit bad2078.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

And then I am stuck, I cannot push anything, or commit anything and I am still in revert mode:

```
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date

$ git commit -a
En la rama master
Su rama está actualizada con «origin/master».
You are currently reverting commit bad2078.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git status
En la rama master
Su rama está actualizada con «origin/master».
You are currently reverting commit bad2078.
  (todos los conflictos corregidos: ejecute «git revert --continue»)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

$ git revert --continue
En la rama master
Su rama está actualizada con «origin/master».
You are currently reverting commit bad2078.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

nothing to commit, working directory clean, what am I missing?

Comment: `bad2078` I feel you, man. Had some sweet `dead909` recently myself ^^'

Comment: Try if it works: `git commit -am 'revert bad2078'`; `git status`

Comment: @SajibKhanit says nothing to commit

Comment: do you see any commit history difference between: `git log master` && `git fetch; git log origin/master`?

Comment: Nope, usually when I revert a commit there should be a "reverted commit" but I dont see any changes in my git log

Answer (score 1):

After resolving a conflict a `revert` commit contains to changes.

So you cannot continue, since by default `git` prevents creating empty commits.

You can:

1. Try `--allow-empty` param, but I don't see how that would be useful to you.
2. Cancel creating revert commit by running `git revert --abort`. And then create a revert commit manually (just by hand making changes).
3. Try to rebase commit to be reverted to be on top of commit log. Most probably your commit you're trying to revert is not the most recent. So putting it on top will allow you to create a revert without any conflicts.
4. Like rebase in previous option but just delete it from branch history.

Two last options will mess with branch history though so if other people are working on this branch then might get issues when rebasing/merging.

Comment: I had this same issue and calling `git commit --allow-empty` worked for me. I had addressed a merge conflict for the actual revert in the previous commit, so I simply reset the branch pointer to that true merge commit (`git reset HEAD^`)

Answer (score 1):

If your conflict resolved files look exactly like what's current in head, then git doesn't think that you'll have any changes to commit, and thus you can't continue your revert.

If you really wanted to have this revert commit added to your branch, then you could modify your conflict resolved files in a single insignificant way, e.g. an extra space in a comment, to trick git into allowing you to complete the revert commit.

But in reality, if your conflict resolved files look exactly like what's currently in head, then you probably don't need to do a git revert in the first place.  Your head is already what you want it to be.  So just abort the revert: **git revert --abort**

Comment: either that or conflict was resolved incorrectly, so there should have been changes but due to problems with resolving the conflict there were none

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, it was caused cause I was trying to revert multiple commit back, The solution for me was to batch revert all to the actual commit I want and restore any file I needed

I aborted the previous revert I was trying, using this:

```
git revert --abort
```

Use:

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD~<NUMBER_OF_COMMIT_AWAY>..HEAD
```

This reverts but leaves or your changes on your work tree
Then you can use the:

```
git restore <FILE>
```

to restore what you need